# Pronunciation of "steak"

Tags: pronunciation

I am wondering why "steak" is pronounced as [steyk] instead of having the "ea" phoneme pronounced as in creak[kreek], cheap[cheep], meat[meet]...

Is it an exception or is there a rule for when to pronounce it one way or the other?

Comment: How do you pronounce *great*?

Comment: If rules to cover every peculiarity of English were devised and published, the necessary volume would make CGEL look tiny.